# How does the following example code exceed the SOQL limits of 100?

Tags: trigger

I was reading about Trigger and Bulk Requests best practices [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm) which quotes:

> If more than 20 records are pulled into this request, the trigger would exceed the SOQL query limit of 100 SELECT statements:

```
trigger MileageTrigger on Mileage__c (before insert, before update) {
    for(mileage__c m : Trigger.new){ 
        User c = [SELECT Id FROM user WHERE mileageid__c = m.Id];
   }
}
```

Looking at the for loop it runs through each record in the request - if 20 records were in the request then the loop would only run 20 times (?) and therefore the SOQL SELECT statement would only run 20 times surely?

How would this trigger exceed the SOQL query limit of 100 SELECT statements if 20 records were in the request?

Comment: Looks like a documentation bug that you can report at the bottom of the page. A colon before m.Id is also missing.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I am quite new to the development side of Salesforce so was wondering if I had missed something! I shall report it as a bug now and mention the colon also :).

Comment: any other trigger associated with this object?

Comment: Whether its 20 or a 100, the main point, as I'm sure you've realised, is to not have queries or DML inside the loops.

Comment: That makes sense, I understood the message just wanted to check I hadn't misunderstood something. From an optimisation point of view it would make sense to take the SELECT out of the loop anyway. I have now reported it so if it is incorrect I'm sure it will get changed eventually.